# Changing request and get a new data stream when using Paging3 library

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library

I have used Jetpack's [Paging 3](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview) library in my project for handling data pagination. I have a use case which when user changes something in search request (for example adding/removing some filters), I have to call API and repopulate my list with new data based on the new search request. But when I create the new `Pager` instance and pass it to my `PagingDataAdapter` adapter, it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Collecting from multiple PagingData concurrently is an illegal operation.
```

My implementation is like this:

**Repository**

```
class Repository {
    fun getDataStream(request: Request): Flow<PagingData<Response>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 10,
                initialLoadSize = 10,
                prefetchDistance = 3
            ),
            initialKey = 1,
            pagingSourceFactory = {
                DataPagingSource(
                    request = request,
                    repository = this
                )
            }
        ).flow
    }

    fun getData(page: Int, request: Request): Result<Response> {
        return remoteDataSource.getData(page, request)
    }
}
```

**DataPagingSource**

```
class DataPagingSource(
    private val request: Request,
    private val repository: Repository
) : PagingSource<Int, Response>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Response> {
        val page = params.key ?: 1
        // Result is a sealed class which has two derived classes: Success and Error
        return when (val result = repository.getData(page, request)) {
            is Result.Success -> {
                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = result.data,
                    nextKey = page.inc(),
                    prevKey = null
                )
            }
            is Result.Error -> LoadResult.Error(
                result.error
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class SomeViewModel(
    private val repository: Repository
): ViewModel() {
    private val _currentRequest = MutableLiveData<Request>()
   
    val data = _currentRequest
        .switchMap {
            repository
                .getDataStream(it)
                .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
                .asLiveData()
        }

    fun updateRequest(request: Request) {
        _currentRequest.postValue(request)
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class SomeFragment: Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: SomeViewModel

    // ...
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...
        viewModel.data.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer {
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    adapter.submitData(it)
                }
            }
        )
    }
    // ...
}
```

It would be great if someone help fix this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I believe if you're observing your Pager as LiveData you need to use the [adapter.submitData(lifecycle, data)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingDataAdapter#submitdata_1) method instead of [adapter.submitData(data)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingDataAdapter#submitdata) in your Fragment, though I also recommend trying out the [distinctUntilChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#distinctUntilChanged(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E)) transformation on your _currentRequest LiveData to limit creating multiple PagingData objects from duplicate requests.

**submitData(lifecycle: Lifecycle, pagingData: PagingData) Documentation**

> This method is typically used when observing a RxJava or LiveData stream produced by Pager. For Flow support, use the suspending overload of submitData, which automates cancellation via CoroutineScope instead of relying of Lifecycle

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingDataAdapter#submitdata_1

**Fragment**

```
    viewModel.data.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        Observer {
            adapter.submitData(lifecycle, it)
        }
    )
```

**ViewModel**

```
    val data = _currentRequest
        // Limit duplicate Requests (Request class should implement equals())
        .distinctUntilChanged()  
        .switchMap {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I did not see this overload of `submitList`. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Nice, this keeps you from having to wrap `adapter.submitData` inside a coroutine

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution to my problem. For `Paging` library to get data using new request model, You have to change request model and then call [invalidate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource#invalidate) on your [PagingDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource). Here is an example:
In **ViewModel** the code changes like this:

```
class SomeViewModel: ViewModel() {    
    private var _dataPagingSource: DataPagingSource? = null
    private val _requestChannel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<Request>()
    
    val data = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
            initialLoadSize = 10,
            prefetchDistance = 3
        ),
        initialKey = 1,
        pagingSourceFactory = {
            DataPagingSource(
                request = _requestChannel.value,
                repository = repository
            ).also {
                dataSource = it
            }
        }
    ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope).asLiveData()

    // ...
    
    // subscribe on requestChannel and invalidate dataSource each time
    // it emits new value
    init {
        _requestChannel
            .asFlow()
            .onEach { _dataPagingSource?.invalidate() }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    // call this method with the new request 
    fun updateRequest(newRequest: Request) {
        _requestChannel.send(newRequest)
    }
}
```

And **Repository** gets like this:

```
class Repository {
    // we do not need getDataStream method here anymore

    fun getData(page: Int, request: Request): Result<Response> {
        return remoteDataSource.getData(page, request)
    }
}
```

I do not know if there is any other way to do this. If you know of other ways it would be great to share it.

Comment: Appreciate you posting your solution, it helped me to finally  get over the hurdle of migrating a portion of my project to using Paging3, which honestly seems like an over-engineered nightmare. @NateisStalling answer was a big help also.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation is like this:

**DataPagingSource**

```
class DataPagingSource(
    private val getRequest:() -> Request,
    private val repository: Repository
) : PagingSource<Int, Response>() {
    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Response> {
        val page = params.key ?: 1
        val request = getRequest()
        // Result is a sealed class which has two derived classes: Success and Error
        return when (val result = repository.getData(page, request)) {
            is Result.Success -> {
                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = result.data,
                    nextKey = page.inc(),
                    prevKey = null
                )
            }
            is Result.Error -> LoadResult.Error(
                result.error
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class SomeViewModel: ViewModel() {    
    
    private var _request :Request = DefaultRequest
    
    val data = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
            initialLoadSize = 10,
            prefetchDistance = 3
        ),
        initialKey = 1,
        pagingSourceFactory = {
            DataPagingSource(
                getRequest = {_request },
                repository = repository
            )
        }
    ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    
    fun updateRequest(newRequest: Request) {
        if(_request != newRequest){
           _request = newRequest
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
viewModel.updateRequest(request)
pageAdapter.refresh()
```

**Jatpack Compose**

```
viewModel.updateRequest(request)
lazyPagingItems.refresh()
```